# If else logic in python based on various conditions

Tags: python-3.x, list, for-loop, optimization

I need a help from the group, I am trying to make the logic based on the below conditions:

1. Have 4 input columns- l1, l2, l3 and two output columns (output_val and output_col) are driven from the input columns
2. If value of **mon is less 5**: Output_val  takes value from l1 and output_col would 'l1'. If l1 is nan, preference is given to l3 and then to l2.
3. **From mon 5 to 7 (inclusive)**: value transitions from l1 to l2:

   ```
       1. In mon 5: output_val: 0.60*l1 + 0.40*l2; output_col: 0.60*l1+0.40*l2

       2. In mon 6:  output_val: 0.50*l1 + 0.50*l2 and output_col: '0.50(l1+l2)' (If any one of them is Nan then 100% is given to the available one like in this case l2 is Nan then 1*l1);                                                                 
       3. In mon 7: output_val: 0.40*l1 + 0.60*l2 and output_col: '0.40*l1+0.60*l2'
   ```
4. **from mon 8-10**: output_val=l2, and output_col='l2' but if l2 is Nan, then preference is given to l1 and then to l3
5. **from mon 11-13**: output_val transitions from l2 to l3 (similar logic as mon 5 to 7)

   ```
       1. in mon 11: output_val: 0.60*l2 + 0.40*l3; output_col: 0.60*l2+0.40*l3
       2. In mon 12:  output_val: 0.50*l2 + 0.50*l3 and output_col: '0.50(l2+l3)' (If any one of them is Nan then 100% is given to the avaiable one); 
       3. In mon 13: output_val: 0.40*l2 + 0.60*l3 and output_col: '0.40*l2 + 0.60*l3'
   ```
6. **from mon 14 to n**: output_val: l3, and output_col=l3; If L3 is not available then first preference is given to l2 and if l1 and l2 is not given then give preference to l1

If all l1, l2, and l3 columns are Nan then output_val=0 and output_col=' '

Input dataframe looks like below:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = {'l1': [2,3,np.nan,3,4,1,23,5,np.nan, 100, 101, 200, 121, 431, 341],
        'l2': [12,13,np.nan,13,14,np.nan,123,15,np.nan, 200, 87, 65, 23, 54, np.nan],
        'l3': [np.nan,333,111,np.nan,334,111,123,5,np.nan, np.nan, 65, 154, 341, np.nan, np.nan],
        'mon':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]}
data = pd.DataFrame(data)
data
```

And output dataframe with two extra columns: 'output_val' and 'output_col' looks like:

```
output_data = {'l1': [2,3,1,3,4,1,23,5,np.nan, 100, 101, 200, 121, 431, 341],
        'l2': [12,13,np.nan,13,14,np.nan,123,15,np.nan, 200, 87, 65, 23, 54, np.nan],
        'l3': [np.nan,333,111,np.nan,334,111,123,5,np.nan, np.nan, 65, 154, 341, np.nan, np.nan],
        'mon':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15],
       'output_val': [2,3,111, 3, 13.44, 1, 678.96, 15, 0, 200, 1357, 2502, 1882, 54, 341],
       'output_col':['l1', 'l1', 'l3', 'l1', '0.60*l1+0.40*l2', '1*l1', '0.40*l1+0.60*l2', 'l2', ' ', 'l2', '0.60*l2+0.40*l3', '0.50*(l2+l3)', '0.40*l2+0.60*l3', 'l2', 'l1']}

output_data = pd.DataFrame(output_data)
```

[image]

Comment: Any suggestions on this question?

Answer (score 0):

**Pandas allows to write the complex UDF**. before jump to the code, not sure if the output data is wrong.

- index 2: the l1 is different between input and output . `data = {'l1': [2,3,np.nan` but in output `output_data = {'l1': [2,3,1`
- index 4 ,the output is not correct based on the formula, `0.6*4 + 0.4*14.0 = 8` instead of `13.44`
- index 6, similar to above, `23*0.4+123*0.6=83.0` instead of 678.96
- index 10-12, similar to above, for instance, `87*0.6+65*0.4 = 78.2` instead of `1357`

---

The example below applied the correction mentioned above.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def calculate_output(row):
    mon = row['mon']
    l1 = row['l1']
    l2 = row['l2']
    l3 = row['l3']

    if pd.isna(l1) and pd.isna(l2) and pd.isna(l3):
        return pd.Series({'output_val': 0, 'output_col': ' '})

    if mon < 5:
        if pd.notna(l1):
            return pd.Series({'output_val': l1, 'output_col': 'l1'})
        elif pd.notna(l3):
            return pd.Series({'output_val': l3, 'output_col': 'l3'})
        else:
            return pd.Series({'output_val': l2, 'output_col': 'l2'})

    if 5 <= mon <=7:
        if pd.isna(l1):
            return pd.Series({'output_val': l2, 'output_col': '1*l2'})
        elif pd.isna(l2):
            return pd.Series({'output_val': l1, 'output_col': '1*l1'})
        elif mon == 5:
            output_val = 0.60 * l1 + 0.40 * l2
            output_col = '0.60*l1+0.40*l2'
            return pd.Series({'output_val': output_val, 'output_col': output_col})
        elif mon == 6:
            output_val = 0.50 * (l1+l2)
            output_col = '0.50*(l1+l2)'
            return pd.Series({'output_val': output_val, 'output_col': output_col})
        elif mon == 7:
            output_val = 0.40 * l1 + 0.60 * l2
            output_col = '0.40*l1+0.60*l2'
            return pd.Series({'output_val': output_val, 'output_col': output_col})

    elif 8 <= mon <= 10:
        if pd.notna(l2):
            return pd.Series({'output_val': l2, 'output_col': 'l2'})
        elif pd.notna(l1):
            return pd.Series({'output_val': l1, 'output_col': 'l1'})
        elif pd.notna(l3):
            return pd.Series({'output_val': l3, 'output_col': 'l3'})
        else:
            return pd.Series({'output_val': 0, 'output_col': ' '})
    if 11 <= mon <= 13:
        if pd.isna(l2):
            return pd.Series({'output_val': l3, 'output_col': '1*l3'})
        elif pd.isna(l3):
            return pd.Series({'output_val': l2, 'output_col': '1*l2'})        
        elif mon == 11:
            output_val = 0.60 * l2 + 0.40 * l3
            output_col = '0.60*l2+0.40*l3'
            return pd.Series({'output_val': output_val, 'output_col': output_col})
        elif mon == 12:
            output_val = 0.50 * (l2+l3)
            output_col = '0.50*(l2+l3)'
            return pd.Series({'output_val': output_val, 'output_col': output_col})
        elif mon == 13:
            output_val = 0.40 * l2 + 0.60 * l3
            output_col = '0.40*l2+0.60*l3'
            return pd.Series({'output_val': output_val, 'output_col': output_col})
    else:
        if pd.notna(l3):
            return pd.Series({'output_val': l3, 'output_col': 'l3'})
        elif pd.notna(l2):
            return pd.Series({'output_val': l2, 'output_col': 'l2'})
        elif pd.notna(l1):
            return pd.Series({'output_val': l1, 'output_col': 'l1'})
        else:
            return pd.Series({'output_val': 0, 'output_col': ' '})
```

Call the UDF

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = {
    "l1": [2, 3, np.nan, 3, 4, 1, 23, 5, np.nan, 100, 101, 200, 121, 431, 341],
    "l2": [12, 13, np.nan, 13, 14, np.nan, 123, 15, np.nan, 200, 87, 65, 23, 54, np.nan],
    "l3": [np.nan,333,111,np.nan,334,111,123,5,np.nan,np.nan,65,154,341,np.nan,np.nan,
    ],
    "mon": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15],
}
data = pd.DataFrame(data)
output_df = data.apply(calculate_output, axis=1)
result_df = pd.concat([data, output_df], axis=1)
```

Validation

```
from pandas.testing import assert_frame_equal

output_data = {'l1': [2,3,np.nan,3,4,1,23,5,np.nan, 100, 101, 200, 121, 431, 341],
       'l2': [12,13,np.nan,13,14,np.nan,123,15,np.nan, 200, 87, 65, 23, 54, np.nan],
       'l3': [np.nan,333,111,np.nan,334,111,123,5,np.nan, np.nan, 65, 154, 341, np.nan, np.nan],
       'mon':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15],
       'output_val': [2,3,111, 3, 8, 1, 83.0, 15, 0, 200, 78.2, 109.5, 213.8, 54, 341],
       'output_col':['l1', 'l1', 'l3', 'l1', '0.60*l1+0.40*l2', '1*l1', '0.40*l1+0.60*l2', 'l2', ' ', 'l2', '0.60*l2+0.40*l3', '0.50*(l2+l3)', '0.40*l2+0.60*l3', 'l2', 'l1']}

output_data = pd.DataFrame(output_data)

assert_frame_equal(result_df, output_data)
```